# how to make sql according to all datagridview selected rows values?

Tags: vb.net

i want to make sql accordindg to all values in datagridview selected rows.the value found in column number 8.i tried this code put it giving only one row

```
            Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow

            For Each dgvRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows




                dt = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("SELECT PT.PT_Name, PT.PT_Agey, PT.PT_Agem, PT.PT_Aged, PT.PT_Date, Result.PT_code, Result.Test_No, Tests.Test_Name, Result.Result, Result.test_ref,Result.test_unit, Result.test_comm, Result.test_date,Result.HorL, PT.PT_Gender, PT.fullname2, PT.age_sex2,PT.PT_Nikname, DR.Dr_Name,Tests.Test_Name,Tests.upnormalshow, Subcategory.Subcat_Name, Maincategory.Maincatname, labdetails.labnme, labdetails.labspecial, labdetails.labadress, labdetails.labphone, labdetails.labtime, labdetails.lablogo, labdetails.labprint, labdetails.labnameenglish, labdetails.labspecialenglish FROM labdetails, ((((PT INNER JOIN (Result INNER JOIN Tests ON Result.Test_No = Tests.Test_No) ON PT.PT_Code = Result.PT_code) INNER JOIN DR ON PT.DR_Code = DR.Dr_Code) INNER JOIN Gender ON (Tests.Test_No = Gender.Test_ID) AND (PT.ageperiod2 = Gender.PT_Gender)) INNER JOIN Subcategory ON Tests.Subcat_ID = Subcategory.Subcat_ID) INNER JOIN Maincategory ON Tests.Maincat_ID = Maincategory.Maincat_ID WHERE (((Result.PT_code)={0}) AND ((Tests.Test_No)<>10 and (Tests.Test_No)<> 11 AND (Tests.Test_No)<> 12 AND (Tests.Test_No)<> 13) and (Tests.Test_No<> 14) and (Tests.Test_No<> 15) and (Tests.Test_No<> 18)  and (Tests.Test_No<> 20) and (Tests.Test_No <> 21) and Tests.Test_No <> 42 and Tests.Test_No <> 76 and Tests.Test_No <> 77 and Tests.Test_No <> 78 and Tests.Test_No <> 79 and Tests.Test_No <> 80 and Tests.Test_No <> 81 and Tests.Test_No <> 92 and Tests.Test_No = {4} AND ((Result.recorded))=Yes) and Result.test_date=#{2}# and PT.PT_Date=#{1}# and Result.PT_ID={3} ORDER BY Result.Test_No;", Txtcode.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), Texid.Text, dgvRow.Cells(8).Value))

            Next
```

Comment: This is susceptible to SQL Injection. You should use a parametertized query instead.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is though. Do you get an error?

Comment: no errors it's just giving may only one row not all selected rows

Comment: Instead of looping and running the query in each iteration, try creating a list of the values in `dgvRow.Cells(8).Value` during the iterations and then after the loop you can use that list with the `IN` keyword in SQL.

Comment: Dim Arr As New ArrayList
                For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                    Arr.Add(dgvRow.Cells(8).Value)
                Next

Comment: i tried to use array.but it giving me no value given for one requried parameter

Comment: You now need to convert that array in a format like this for your SQL `IN ('value1', 'value2')` - The simplest way would be to use a string builder and escape the apostrophes yourself to prevent SQL injection. If want to us  a param though, you should be able to create a param that is of table value to pass into the IN clause of the SQL. It might work with an array or you might need a `DataTable`. I don't feel like testing so I'm just giving you possible approaches. I think that both answer you got are wrong. I'm considering making my own answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you're trying to say:
i think you're trying to make a sql based on the selected row of datagridview
simply use the: `DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("GridviewColumnNameHere").Value`
Hope this will help.
No need looping.

```
 Dim sql As String = "Select * from TableName where ColumnName = @columnName"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection()
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("ColumnNameInGridview").Value)
```

Comment: You're wrong and the OP already has this SQL. Modify this to use the IN keyword from the selected rows and it will be acceptable.

Comment: only giving me on row not all selected rows

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selectdatatable function returns a DataTable. The problem is that your variable, dt, is being overwritten on every iteration so, will end up with a single row. I have adjusted the Where clause to use parameters. The Load method will merge the records returned on each iteration. I think this only works if there is a Primary Key returned. You will have to check the datatypes of the fields because I had to guess. Be sure that your parameter values are converted to the proper type. It doesn't make much sense to me for Tests.Test_No to not equal a bunch of numbers and then equal another number.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select...WHERE 
            Result.PT_code=@PTCode 
            AND Tests.Text_No Not In (10,11,12,13,14,15,18,20,21,42,76,77,78,79,80,81,92)
            AND Tests.Test_No = @TextNo
            AND Result.recorded=Yes
            AND Result.test_date=@TestDate
            AND PT.PT_Date=@PTDate
            AND Result.PT_ID=@TexID
            ORDER BY Result.Test_No;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PTCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txtcode.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextNo", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TestDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PTDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Texid.Text
            cn.Open()
            For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                cmd.Parameters("@TextNo").Value = CInt(dgvRow.Cells(8).Value)
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot the @ sign in front of TestDate.` cmd.Parameters.Add("@TestDate"` I have corrected my answer.